# Date selection for produce report using VB.NET, SQL Server 2008 and Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Kindly need your help to solve my problem related to subject above.

I need to create a program to filter a report, below is my code

```
FrLaporan_Penjualan.CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = _
  "{TDetail_Transaksi.Tanggal_Transaksi} >= DateTime(" & Format(DateTimePicker1.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & ") " & " 
and {TDetail_Transaksi.Tanggal_Transaksi} <= Datetime(" & Format(DateTimePicker2.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & ")"

FrLaporan_Penjualan.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
FrLaporan_Penjualan.Show()
```

After I run the program, I keep receiving the same error message the ")" is missing,
please help and really appreciated

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one too many ampersands and double quotes in the first part of your formula. I also don't know what the underscore is for at the very beginning; So give this a try:

```
    FrLaporan_Penjualan.CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = 
  ("{TDetail_Transaksi.Tanggal_Transaksi} >= DateTime(" & Format(DateTimePicker1.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & ")" 
and {TDetail_Transaksi.Tanggal_Transaksi} <= Datetime(" & Format(DateTimePicker2.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & ")")

FrLaporan_Penjualan.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
FrLaporan_Penjualan.Show();
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be semi-colons after each of these? FrLaporan_Penjualan.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
FrLaporan_Penjualan.Show();

Comment: hi @campagnolo_1 the problem is already solve, thank you for the advice